# PHP Compilation

Tags: php, compilation, interpreter

I would like to understand how the PHP compilation process works.

Assuming I have a file called `funcs.php` and this file has three functions, if I `include` or `require` it, will all the three functions be compiled during the file load? Or will the source code be read and kept in memory, until I call them and this call will trigger the compilation process?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean with a vanilla release from php.net and no extensions that fiddle wih this process?

Comment: Yes, that´s what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, all three functions will be read in and prepared for execution** and their names will be saved into a table and from then on be *reserved*. So, syntax errors will also appear if you don't execute the function.

This process doesn't really consume much time, but you should try to reduce the amount of code and remove unused stuff. Mainly because it could cause problems after a major PHP upgrade.